# How to enable window compositing (Compiz) in Ubuntu MATE?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, compiz, mate, ubuntu-mate

I know that other desktops support window compositing with Compiz.

Is it possible to enable such functionality on MATE DE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

One should:

1. open `mate-tweak` (*System->Preferences->Look and Feel->MATE Tweak*)
2. go to *Windows* tab
3. in *Window manager* area switch *Select a window manager* to *Compiz (Advanced GPU accelerated desktop effects)* as shown on screenshot below:

   [image: MATE Tweak - choose Compiz]

Other options are:

- *Marco (No compositor)*
- *Marco (Software compositor)*
- *Marco (Compton GPU compositor)*

Note: you can switch back to *Marco (No compositor)* if you want simple traditional desktop.