# What's an alternate to Compiz's window manager for Ubuntu 21.10 for window management shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, compiz, window, application-switcher

I'm planning on reducing my mouse usage over time. As such i came to know about Compiz window manager on this amazing site. But the official page for Compiz's compositing window manager says it was last updated in 2019 which means it's not compatible with my current distro which is 21.10. My aim is to customize the switching of windows as the default shortcuts aren't intuitive for me.The default shortcuts in 21.10 only allow a uni-directional switching of the windows. It leaves with the only option that either I have to come a full circle of rotation if i miss the targeted window or use the arrow keys instead which breaks the flow. The sweet spot for me would be to use a combination of shortcuts like Super+z and Super+x for backward and forward rotation of switching the windows respectively. How can i achieve this? If there's an alternative to Compiz, what is it?

PS: I know i can go to activities overview to switch windows but it doesn't work as there's no way i can select a window using arrow keys if my mouse is not in the proximity of one of the windows.

Comment: If you press Alt+Tab and keep Alt pressed, you can then (while still keeping Alt pressed) use Tab to switch windows forward and Shift-Tab to switch backwards or simply use the arrow keys. Good alternative is Super+[0-9] to switch to one of the apps pinned to the dock.

Comment: FYI Compiz is still usable on traditional desktop environments like [MATE](https://askubuntu.com/a/1049995/66509) with some really [cool things](https://askubuntu.com/a/1295733/66509).